# Scraping dropdown menu content with R

Tags: r, screen-scraping, rvest

I have a problem with [this site](https://scansante.fr/applications/casemix_ghm_cmd)

With Rvest, I can scrape all the table in the page, EXCEPT the menu at the end of the table, the one with a scroll bar. And the content of this menu is just what I want.
There are 9-digit codes like this one `010007300` that I want to grab.

This is a bit of the code I want to fetch :

```
  <option value="010007300" disabled="">010007300 - CLINIQUE AMBULATOIRE CENDANEG</option>
  <option value="010007987" disabled="">010007987 - CH HAUTEVILLE-LOMPNES</option>
  <option value="010008407" disabled="">010008407 - CH DU HAUT BUGEY</option>
  <option value="010009132" disabled="">010009132 - CHIC AIN VAL DE SAONE</option>
  <option value="010780054" disabled="">010780054 - CH BOURG EN BRESSE</option>
  <option value="010780062" disabled="">010780062 - CH BUGEY SUD</option>
  <option value="010780096" disabled="">010780096 - CH MONTPENSIER TREVOUX</option>
  <option value="010780120" disabled="">010780120 - CH DE MEXIMIEUX</option>
  <option value="010780138" disabled="">010780138 - CH DE PONT DE VAUX</option>
  <option value="010780195" disabled="">010780195 - CLINIQUE CONVERT BOURG-EN-B.</option>
  <option value="010780203" disabled="">010780203 - HÔPITAL PRIVÉ D'AMBERIEU</option>
```

The whole thing sits whithin a table, this is the code I've used in R :

```
url_finess_list <- "https://scansante.fr/applications/casemix_ghm_cmd"

finess_page = read_html(url_finess_list)

finess_codes = finess_page %>%
  html_nodes("table") %>% .[1] %>%
  html_table() %>% .[[1]]
```

Comment: Could it be that the `<option>`-tags are loaded dynamically so that you need to use `RSelenium` instead of `rvest`? (Unfortunately I cannot try it out now due to technical reasons, but I could do so in two days.)

Comment: RSelenium seemed more adapted to this situation indeed. Whilst I needed that quite quickly, I simply right clicked and inspect, then copied outer html and pasted it in a spreadsheet. All values were copied at once in separate rows fortunately. Not quite conventional I confess but in this particular case, it worked fine.